# how to get the drive letter where project located in visual studio community 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Suppose the project file (.vcxproj) is located in f:\project\proj001\test.vcxproj

In the project setting (visual studio community 2017), I want to set the Output directory to f:\project\bin

But I don't want to hard code the drive letter, because in other machine there is no f drive.

It would be nice to write something like %DRIVE_LETTER_OF_PROJ%\project\bin

Is it possible?

Comment: You have to leverage the macros that are available, you can see them when use the drop-down when you edit the setting and click the Macros button.  $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration) is the default, messing with it starts at minus 10 points.  None for the drive, you are asking for `$(ProjectDir)..\bin`.  Keep in mind that having the Debug build overwrite the Release build is a bad idea, too many accidents when you have to explicitly rebuild.

Comment: Or possibly `$(SolutionDir)bin` when you store projects in a subdir of the solution (like proj001).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions with built-in variables like this:

```
$(ProjectDir.Substring(0,2))\project\bin
```

The variable `$(ProjectDir.Substring(0,2))` will return just the 2-character drive such as `C:` or `D:`, etc.

Here's an example where I wanted to move the Intermediate publish directory to outside of a website project folder, but have it dynamically work for any drive letter where the solution resides:

```
<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionDir.Substring(0,2))\Publish\Web\obj\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
```